# Multiplying a currency value and percentage value by cell reference

Tags: google-sheets

When using google sheets to multiply two cells (E5 and E6), one being a percentage with a *decimal place* (26.77%) and the other a currency value ($300,000). The value produced is off by a certain amount. I was able to fix this issue by multiplying the currency value with the percentage *typed in* (E5 and 26.77%). Also using a normal calculator will get you the same answer as (E5 and 26.77%) not (E5 and E6). I was wondering if anyone knows why this is the case or how to fix this issue? And it only applies to percentages with a decimal place.

Comment: I get the same answer doing any of the variations mentioned in your post (i.e., 80310). I'm guessing that your 26.77% is the result of some calculation rather than manually a manually-entered amount. And if that is the case, you may have merely formatted the cell to show 26.77% whereas it is actually 26.7712 % or something like that in memory due to the preceding calculation(s) that resulted in that amount. The only way for us to offer any insight would be if you share a link to the sheet or a copy of it here.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can always wrap your formula in ROUND(...) to have it truncated to two decimal places after calculation.

Comment: Ok, thanks again!